# Webapp username security

Tags: python, web-applications, security

I'm creating a webapplication in Python (and Flask) where a user can register with their wanted username. I would like to show their profile at /user/ and have a directory on the server for each user.

What is the best way to make sure the username is secure for both a url and directory? I read about people using the urlsafe methods in base64, but I would like to have a string that is related to their username for easy recognition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The generic term for such URL-safe values is ["slug"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slug_%28web_publishing%29), and the process of generating one is called "slugification", or "to slugify". People generally use a regular expression to do so; here is one (sourced from [this article on the subject](http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/5/)), using only stdlib modules:

```
import re
from unicodedata import normalize

_punct_re = re.compile(r'[\t !"#$%&\'()*\-/<=>?@\[\\\]^_`{|},.]+')

def slugify(text, delim=u'-'):
    """Generates an slightly worse ASCII-only slug."""
    result = []
    for word in _punct_re.split(text.lower()):
        word = normalize('NFKD', word).encode('ascii', 'ignore')
        if word:
            result.append(word)
    return unicode(delim.join(result))
```

The linked article has another 2 alternatives requiring additional modules.

Comment: Ah, the correct term is useful :-). I'll have a Google, but maybe you can answer me if it is safe to use this slug for a username and directory name?

Comment: Only slashes ('/') are dangerous in UNIX filenames, and back-slashes ('\') on Windows, and they escaped. No idea what you'll be storing the usernames in to make any security assessments there, but they'd be fine for URL use.